# Hibernate Subclass which has multiple discriminator values

Tags: hibernate

Hello I have a Subclass which needs to cover multiple Discriminator Values.

something like:

@DiscriminatorValue(value = "ACT","DNR","ATT" )

would do me perfect.

we have existing data where several discriminators can be mapped to one class (as they are similar types of what our system will consider the same thing)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use DiscriminatorFormula:

```
// Base class
@DiscriminatorFormula("case when value in ('ACT','DNR','ATT') then 1 
   when 'OTH' then 2 else 3 end")

// Subclass 
@DiscriminatorValue("1") // maps to ACT, DNR, ATT
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what OP asked for.

Comment: Thanks a million Brian.  I was doing this same thing but putting the @DiscriminatorFormula in the subclass . (Duh).  This is working perfectly

Comment: Good. I cannot find any documentaion or example about `@DiscriminatorFormula`. When can I find it?

Comment: [Sangdol] Here are some links: http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Server/1.0/html/Hibernate_Annotations_Reference_Guide/entity-hibspec-inheritance.html and http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#d5e3307

Comment: If you use JOINED inheritance strategy then @DiscriminatorFormula is not allowed

Answer (score 2):

A subclass has exactly 1 discriminator value.

You can add additional subclasses under the existing subclass for the extra discriminator values. Subclasses need not have additional properties or behavior.

Comment: Correct, but that value can be obtained via a formula that works on multiple values, e.g., `<discriminator formula="case when CLASS_TYPE in ('a', 'b', 'c') then 0 else 1 end" type="Int32"/>` (see [link] (http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#mapping-declaration-discriminator)) NOTE: I'm including this because I wanted to know how to do it inside the Hibernate XML, and this may help someone in future.